# Want to change full line in conf file with bash please guide me

Tags: bash, shell

I have this line in my conf files.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc.com/abc.com_fullchain.txt;
```

So I want to change this as

```
ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/nginx/abc.com/abc.com_fullchain.txt;
```

How can I do this in multiple `*.conf` files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to achieve this, like so:

```
sed -i 's/ssl_certificate \/etc\/nginx\/sites-enabled\/abc.com\/abc.com_fullchain.txt;/ssl_certificate \/var\/www\/ssl\/nginx\/abc.com\/abc.com_fullchain.txt;/g' ./*.conf
```

Note that the forward slashes in the directory strings needed to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is happening when you run this?

Comment: @binbashbosh The `/g` at the end of the command was not necessary in my environment. What does it provide?

Comment: I am getting this "sed: -e expression #1, char 110: unterminated `s' command"
Also, I have multiple conf files with a name like abc.com.conf; xyz.com.conf etc.... So I don't want to run this single command for 300 files. So please guide me how can i do this

Comment: Have you tried the command listed in the edit? As for limiting which files you apply this to, you can replace `*.conf` in the command with the full name of the file you want. If all the files you want to change share a common pattern in their name, you can use [pattern matching in Bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns). Since you haven't given any more specific information about your use case, I'll leave it to you to do some research on how to match the filenames that you want.